# Regex .* expression extracts only a part of the characters I want to extract?

Tags: ruby, regex, html-parsing

I have this string:

```
rder=3D"0" width=3D"650">=0D=0A <tr>=0D=0A <td valign=3D"top">=0D=0A <p>=0D=0A <strong>Hi Mike Tyson</strong>,<br/>=0D=0A =
```

I want to extract `Mike Tyson` from the string. Everything but the name is always the same in the above string, so my first clue would be to just use this regex:

```
[^rder=3D"0" width=3D"650">=0D=0A <tr>=0D=0A <td valign=3D"top">=0D=0A <p>=0D=0A <strong>Hi ].*[^<\/strong>,<br\/>=0D=0A =]
```

However, this outputs `Mike Ty` instead of `Mike Tyson`. Any ideas?

Comment: can you give the full html code for this?

Comment: You don't have understand the use of the character classes. Take a look at this link:http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: This very popular question and first answer summarise generally how regex-ing into HTML is received: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags  - TL;DR: you'll get away with it in a few places, but as soon as it starts to cost you time to debug, cease and get an HTML parser (Ruby's `nokogiri` is good) to do your work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets make the entire match a character class

This expression will match Mike Tyson

`(?<=rder=3D"0" width=3D"650">=0D=0A <tr>=0D=0A <td valign=3D"top">=0D=0A <p>=0D=0A <strong>Hi ).*?(?=<\/strong>,<br\/>=0D=0A =)`

Live Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/OaK2ZmbSPh

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to avoid having match groups.